# Reading logs with filters programmatically

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I am trying to read the user entered logs using `log.i()` programmatically as follows,

```
try {
        Log.i("logs", "inside log.java");
        String filter = "logcat ";
        filter += "-d ";
        filter += "logs:I";
        // String[] command = new String[] { "logcat", "-s" , "logs:"+filter
        // };
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filter);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        log = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            log.append(line);
            log.append("\n");
        }
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(onCleared);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logview);
        tv.setText(log.toString());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("Logging", ex.toString());
    }

    // convert log to string
    final String logString = new String(log.toString());

    // create text file in SDCard
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "logcat.txt");

    try {
        // to write logcat in text file
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        // Write the string to the file
        osw.write(logString);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it simply shows a black screen . but when i try to run the command in `adb shell` it works . my `adb` code is,

```
 adb logcat -s logs:I
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem while trying to log files to text programmatically. I think what's happening here is that the log reading process is blocking the UI (main) thread, resulting in the black screen.

Try putting the entire log reading process into an ASyncTask. That made it work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```